# why we use here (int) with (space)?

Tags: java, string

```
int lastSpace = fullName.lastIndexOf(" ");
```

here all the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class java_13 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("Enter your full name");
    String fullName = input.nextLine();

    int firstSpace = fullName.indexOf(" ");
    String firstName = fullName.substring(0, firstSpace);

    int lastSpace = fullName.lastIndexOf(" ");
    String lastName = fullName.substring(lastSpace + 1);

    System.out.println("\n" + lastName + ", " + firstName);
```

also why we use ( +1 ) 
here

```
String lastName = fullName.substring(lastSpace + 1);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the space divides firstName and lastName.

The input is supposed to look like "firstName lastName". If you take the position of the " " space from it, then the "lastName" part begins on the next character, hence the +1 to the position for getting the substring.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, the index starts with 0.
For example :

```
String name = "Moataz Mohamed";
name[0]='M';
name[1]='o'; 
...
name[6]=' '; //Space
```

Space separates First name and Last name.
Hence, 
`0 to index[" "]-1` is First name
`index[" "]+1 to length()`  is Second name

Hope its clear now.

Answer (score 2):

Here the full name is composed of a first name and the last name, this code search the first blank space in order to separate the first name from the last name 
But I recommend allowing the user to enter both of the last and the first name instead of the full name because it is impossible to know how much words compose the first name and the same thing for the last name.

Answer (score 2):

As @0x01 mentioned, you get the index of the space, but in last name is beginning at position with index +1, that is the reason, just check this outputs

```
{...}
    public static final String NAME1 = "Julian Papadopulos";
    public static final String NAME2 = "John von Bahnhof";

    public static final char SPLITCHAR = ' ';
{...}
public static void splitNamesBySpaceIndex() {
        // name1
        int firstSpace = NAME1.indexOf(" ");
        int lastSpace = NAME1.lastIndexOf(" ");

        String firstName = NAME1.substring(0, firstSpace);
        String lastName = NAME1.substring(lastSpace + 1);
        System.out.println("lastname: \'" + lastName + "\', firstname: \'" + firstName + "\'");

        lastName = NAME1.substring(lastSpace);
        System.out.println("lastname: \'" + lastName + "\', firstname: \'" + firstName + "\'");
    }
```

Output looks like:

```
lastname: 'Papadopulos', firstname: 'Julian'
lastname: ' Papadopulos', firstname: 'Julian'
```

As you can see, in the second case you will parse last name like `' Papadopulos'`, which is not correct, its caused by taking start index the index of the space- this is the reason, why you need position with index +1.

Answer (score 2):

```
This is like this...

FIRSTNAME LASTNAME
012345678901234567

FIRSTNAME Starts from 0 
Index of " " is 9 
LASTNAME Starts from 10 

That is why you need to add (+1) here 
indexOf(" ") {9} but you have to start with LASTNAME which is at 10
If you do not add (+1) then Output will be " LASTNAME"
```